# Laravel 5.4 not registrating users to database,

Tags: mysql, authentication, laravel-5.4

I'm simply trying to make my register form submit to my database, but my problem is you enter the info to the form press submit and it just reloads the page and does not send anything to the database.

originally it would submit what i entered but when you went to login it would just reload the page and not redirect, so i changed some stuff one thing lead to another now its not doing anything and i cannot pin-point the problems.

RegisterController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = ('index');

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin');
    }
```

routes/web.php

```
<?php

Auth::routes();

 Route::get('/index', 'HomeController@index');

  Route::prefix('/admin')->group(function() {

    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
  });

Route::prefix('/admin')->group(function() {
Route::get('register', 'Auth\AdminRegisterController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\AdminRegisterController@register')->name('admin.register');
});


Route::get('about', function () {
    return view('about');
});


Route::get('advertise', function () {
    return view('advertise');
});

Route::get('index', function () {
        return view('index');  })->middleware('auth');
```

register.blade.php

```
@extends('header')

<div id="form-su" style="background-color: #d8b6ff" >

<h3 class="signuph"> Register </h3>
</div>

<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.register') }}"> 

<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">

@if ($errors->has('name'))
    <span class="help-block">
     <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
      </span>
@endif

 <div class="div-su {{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
 <input  class="signup-menu2{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" " type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="  Name.." required >


<input  class="signup-menu2{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" " type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="  Email.." required >
 </br>


<input  class="signup-menu2{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" type="password" name="password" placeholder="  Password.."  required > 

 @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
            </span>

 </br>

<label> confirm password
<input  class="signup-menu2 " type="password" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="  Confirm Password.."  required > 
</label>




@endif
 </br>


<button class="signup-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> Sign Up </button>
</form> </br>


<p class="forgotten-password" href=""> Forgotten password?</p> </br>
<p class="log-in-here" a href="">Log in here </p> </br>


</div>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

also for some reason the confirm password input does not show on the form in the browser, but if you submit the form it pops up... whys that?

i know that you may need to see other pages so don't hesitate to ask for them

i appreciate any help guys,

Comment: What are you trying to do? You show `RegisterController` but your form action points to `admin.register` route, which uses `AdminRegisterController`

Comment: originally it was just register ... all i need it to do is let users sign up which it submits their inputs from the form to my database